# ASP.NET MVC editor templates and Html.EditorFor(...) - how to disambiguate the type name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

When using this HTML helper in Razor syntax:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop1)
```

... the convention is to render the view under  `Views/<CrtView|Shared>/EditorTemplates/Prop1TypeName.cshtml`.

So far so good. Notice that if the (qualified) type of Prop1 is `my.org.ns.TheType`, the file `TheType.cshtml` will be rendered.

But if I have a model with `.Prop1` and `.Prop2`, and :

```
Prop1.GetType().FullName == "my.org.ns1.TheType";
Prop2.GetType().FullName == "my.org.ns2.TheType";  //same type name but different namespace
```

and I call this Razor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop1)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop2)
```

...I can't get it to display *different* views for the different types.

Is there a way to disambiguate this?

Maybe there's more than I know about the naming convention for the `.cshtml` file?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to specify the name of the editor to use.  With this, you would name your EditorTemplates `First.cshtml` and `Second.cshtml`, then in your View, do this.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop1, "First")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop2, "Second")
```

However, I would recommend avoiding reusing the same type name in the same project, even if they have different namespaces.  This will cause confusion for someone reading the code, maybe even you down the road.  That is a bigger issue than the framework not knowing what template to use.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation of not using the same type name, but it's not possible in this case - this is generated code and I can't control what type names are generated.

Answer (score 5):

When examining the ASP.NET MVC [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs) (line 164):

```
 // TODO: Make better string names for generic types
 yield return fieldType.Name;
```

It's seems that the development team is aware that this simplified approach (`fieldType.Name` for complex type) could be potentiality ambiguous. i hope they'll find an elegant way to let us choose templates in a more flexible way.

In the meantime, you can simply use the `[UIHint]` attribute, as follows:

```
[UIHint("ns1.TheType")]
public TheType Prop1 { get; set; }

[UIHint("ns2.TheType")]
public TheType Prop2 { get; set; }
```

**Update (as per your comment):**

The `[UIHint]` can only be used on a property or a field, hence you can't use it to decorate your class.

However, you can create your own attribute that derives from `UIHintAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyUIHintAttribute : UIHintAttribute
{
    public MyUIHintAttribute(string templateName) : base(templateName)
    {
    }
}
```

Then decorate your classes:

```
[MyUIHint("ns1.TheType")]
public class TheType
{
    ....
}

[MyUIHint("ns2.TheType")]
public class TheType
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: +1, although not very helpful for my particular scenario (the model is a list of items of heterogenous types). Is `UIHint` (or is there another attribute) that can be applied at the `*type* level instead of  decorating properties?

Answer (score 2):

**You don't necessarily have to use the conventions. You can have your own template names.**

Like this,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop1,"TheType_1")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop2,"TheType_2")
```

where "TheType_1" & "TheType_2" are the different template names for different types.
This is one of [six different overload methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) available.